# replacing strings inside echo

Tags: php

I'm trying to replace spaces with the `-` in between the titles through my URL's, but having a hard time doing so inside an `echo` command.

The string:

```
<a href=\"entry/{$article['id']} {$article['news_title']}\">
    {$article['news_title']}
</a>
```

I tried doing:

```
<a href=\"entry/{$article['id']}
        .'-'
        .stripslashes(str_replace(' ', '-', {$article['news_title']}))
        .'\">
    {$article['news_title']}
</a>
```

But it's throwing out errors. Here's the full code:

```
 echo("
        <a href=\"entry/{$article['id']} {$article['news_title']}\">
            {$article['news_title']}
        </a>
      ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to end the quotes so you can call functions and use concatenation.

```
echo "
    <a href=\"entry/{$article['id']} {" . stripslashes(str_replace(' ', '-', $article['news_title'])) . "\">{$article['news_title']}</a>        

  ";
```

However, for readability, I suggest using a variable:

```
$title_url = stripslashes(str_replace(' ', '-', $article['news_title']));
echo("
    <a href=\"entry/{$article['id']} {$title_url}\">{$article['news_title']}</a>        

  ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
<?php 
$url = "entry/".{$article['id']}.{$article['news_title']};
$encoded = rawurlencode ( $url );
echo '<a href="'.$encoded.'">'.{$article['news_title']}.'</a>';
?>
```